# DMLOptions 'useDefaultRule' for an account's update - not working

Tags: dml, assignment-rules, territory

I'm trying to assign DML options to an account's update. It's working with the insert, but not wit an update.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10];
Database.update(accs,dmlOpts);
```

After running that, no territory rules are running. I know how to do it with Visualforce, but no idea using just APEX (as I really need).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the docs at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm

> The Database.DMLOptions object supports assignment rules for cases and
>   leads, but not for accounts or territory management.

The correct assignment on insert must be based on some default value being set?

Comment: I know manual says that, but I can force it with javascript and visualforce, so It should be a backdoor with APEX too. Here you can find other information for useDefaultRule with accounts: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_headers.htm

Comment: you are right indeed. Learned something new :-) But it looks like the backdoor is closed in Apex. This idea has been running for years: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqRXAA0  A workaround is described here, bypassing the auto-assignment:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008yGQIAY

Comment: maybe create a soap call from apex to your own org? Not sure if would be blocked, though..